# API for fetching Support tickets for a user from salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am working with Salesforce API and need to fetch all the support tickets against a user but I am not able to find any REST API for fetching the tickets.
Can anyone let me know if there is such REST API is there?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard object in Salesforce called a Support Ticket. You may be using the Case standard object, or a custom object; regardless, it won't have its own API endpoint.

You'll want to use the [Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) REST endpoint to execute a SOQL query to locate the records you need.